# Column with keyword name as argument of LEN function

Tags: t-sql

How to get length of column with name "text"?

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT LEN([text]) AS mylength FROM mytable
```

Error is:
Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of len function.

Comment: Perhaps describe in more detail than "doesn't work" what happens? Do you get an error message (if so, what)? Unexpected results? (If so, maybe give some example data and your *expected* results). Something else?

Comment: Why are you using `text` datatype?

Comment: I can't change name of column. Yes, type is TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DATALENGTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) . `LEN()` cannot be used on columns of type '`TEXT`'

```
SELECT DATALENGTH([text]) AS mylength FROM mytable
```

BTW: text is a very poor choice of name for a column. Also, the TEXT datatype has been deprecated. Use `varchar(max)` instead (or `nvarchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)`)